# Java - Get 'View' of Collection by Type/Interface

Tags: java, collections, guava

I need to store a number of objects in a `Set`. Sometimes I want to iterate over *everything* in the `Set`, and sometimes I'd like to iterate over only that implement a particular interface. Some objects will implement several of the interfaces that I want a view on.

Is there a design pattern or Guava/Java class that allows views-by-type on a `Set` or other collection? Preferably in the most efficient manner possible, as this code will be central to a core game loop getting called every 17 milliseconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Guava --

```
Sets.filter(set, Predicates.instanceOf(Foo.class));
```

Comment: Traversal will iterate over the entire set, which is more or less inevitable if you're unwilling to create a specialized data structure for the job.

Comment: You can also use `Iterables.filter(Iterable<?> unfiltered, Class<T> type)` if an `Iterable` view suffices. It's an overload of `Iterables.filter(Iterable<T> unfiltered, Predicate<? super T> predicate)` that casts the returned `Iterable` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about saving the objects in a hashtable?

```
Hashtable<String,Set<YourObject>> ht = new Hashtable<String,Set<YourObject>>();
```

Where the String is the types name. That way you can choose what to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The downside of this approach is that when storing something that implements multiple interfaces, I'd need to either reflect to find all interfaces of interest, or have them 'baked in' at compile time (a series of `instanceof`s, and an add call for each match).